# I've got an error, but I don't even know where to start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity, and this error is coming up:

InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling to Input System package in Player Settings.
PlayerController.RetrieveMoveInput () (at Assets/Scripts/Controllers/PlayerController.cs:13)
Move.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Capabilities/Move.cs:30)

It says this error comes up 999+ times, and I don't even know what its talking about. I'll post my scripts, and I'll post a screenshot including my console and all my objects in my scene:

[image]

Scripts: file:///Users/elliotsmyth/help%20me/Assets/Scripts/Controllers/AIController.cs
file:///Users/elliotsmyth/help%20me/Assets/Scripts/Controllers/InputController.cs
file:///Users/elliotsmyth/help%20me/Assets/Scripts/Controllers/PlayerController.cs
file:///Users/elliotsmyth/help%20me/Assets/Scripts/Checks/Ground.cs
file:///Users/elliotsmyth/help%20me/Assets/Scripts/Capabilities/Move.cs

Comment: how should anyone know why the error occurs when you don't provide the code of your `PlayerControler`?

Comment: I think the exception message is clear enough. It told you that you can only use one type of input system. Which one you don't know? Input System package or UnityEngine.Input class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means you imported the `InputSystem` package into your project and have set the `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Player` → `Other Settings` → `Active Input handling` to only the new `Input System`.

However, somewhere in your code you are still trying to use the old `Input` class e.g.

```
Input.GetKeyDown(...)
```

or

```
Input.mousePosition
```

etc. which is no longer available due to your settings.

Solution:

- You either want to find that usage of `Input` and replace it by something going through the new `Input System` (so basically your `InputActions`)
- Or you adjust the `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Player` → `Other Settings` → `Active Input handling` to use a hybrid approach and allow both input systems simultaneously by setting it to `Both`

[image]